# While loop to display all data after SELECT query

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

I know this might be a very basic question, but I am new to php and databases, I'm trying to figure out a while condition that will keep while loop running until all (would be also nice to know how to do it for fixed amount) of data is taken form database.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM icecreams");
$stmt -> execute();
$row = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So now I need to figure out what while condition I need, the logic is

```
while (there is data to fetch) {

  echo "<h1>$row['flavour']</h1>";
  echo "...";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an **array** containing all of the result set rows, whereas [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns a **single row** from the result-set.

**`fetchAll()` Usage:**

```
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($array as $row) {
    # code...
}
```

**`fetch()` Usage:**

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   # code...
}
```

If you're going to use this for printing HTML, the second option seems nicer. For small recordsets, the performance difference shouldn't really matter, but if you're working with a lot of records, then `fetchAll()` might be a little slower,  as it tries to map the entire data into a single array at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM properties");
$stmt -> execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

//$row['column_name']

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll` does fetch everything as an associative array (as flag `FETCH_ASSOC` tells). It does it automatically for, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: But in terms of displaying data as html, how would I achieve it? While (fetchAll(..)) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this then you will see that you have all of your data in an array already:

```
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';
```

So now you can simply loop the items an access the data:

```
foreach($row as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k.'<br>'; // this will show you what row # you are on, sometimes useful :)
    echo $v['title'].'<br>';
    // etc....
}
```